# How to access a control inside an ajaxmodalpopup in javascript?

Tags: javascript, ajaxcontroltoolkit

Inside an Ajax popup I have a GridView.

I want to access the GridView from javascript.

As it is inside popup I am unable to use document.getElementById

I used document.GetElementsByTagName and accessed popup in javascript.

How to traverse to the gridview inside that popup?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can't you just use something like:

```
document.getElementById('<%= YOUR_GRIDVIEW_ID.ClientID %>')
```

?

Answer (score 0):

If your "ajax popup" is a DOM iframe, use `myIframe.contentDocument` to get its DOM document.

Since you accessed the popup with `document.getElementsByTagName`, you obviously know the tagName of your popup. From there, you can use [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms533054%28VS.85%29.aspx) to find the way to access your popup's content.

Comment: I used ModalPopupExtender of AjaxToolKit. I have no idea of how to go with myIframe.currentDocument.

Comment: Ok you don't know about iframes, and I don't know about .net. But you can find out.